# Convert RSS pubdate to timestamp in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, rss

My table feeds in mysql has a RSS `timestring` column named `pubDate`.
I would like to add an additional column `pubDate_Date` and insert the RSS `timestring` as a real date.

I have created the additional column `formatted as DATE` and try to use the following code to update the new column with data, but somehow I cannot get it working. Am a newbie here.

```
function pubDateToMySql($str){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($str));
};

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM feeds ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $pubDate = $row["pubDate"];
    $pubDate_Date = pubDateToMySql($pubDate); 
    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, "UPDATE feeds SET pubDate_Date = 
    $pubDate_Date WHERE ID = $id");
} 
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$str` ?

Comment: $str is the RSS string in markup Tue, 23 Jan 2018 16:59:03 +0100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this post, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
UPDATE feeds SET pubDate_Date = STR_TO_DATE(pubDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %T')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this SQL query

```
UPDATE feeds 
SET pubDate_Date = $pubDate_Date 
WHERE ID = $id
```

you must use date value in `'` like this:

```
UPDATE feeds 
SET pubDate_Date = '$pubDate_Date' 
WHERE ID = $id
```

also check type of column `pubDate_Date` in database

Comment: pubDate_Date is of type datetime.

Comment: I have changed the line to 
    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, "UPDATE feeds SET pubDate_Date = '$pubDate_Date' WHERE ID = '$id'");
}
But this does not work.